# ASP MVC/Linq - remove objects from query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I need to remove certain items from a Linq query based on a search filter provided by the user (in this case, it would be an agent's name).

Basically the first query grabs all the information from the relevant table, and I need to filter out the ones that do not have a name corresponding with the one specified.

Below is the code I was trying to use, but obviously the `followUpItems.Remove()` isn't an actual method, just looking for something along those lines. Since `followUpItems` was defined as a `var` instead of a list, I'm wondering if this is possible?

```
        var followUpItem = from follow in db.FollowUpItems
                           where (follow.TableName.Equals(TableName) || TableName.Equals("%")) &&
                                 (follow.IssueType.Equals(IssueType) || IssueType.Equals("%")) &&
                                 (follow.Status.Equals(Status) || Status.Equals("%"))
                           orderby follow.Id
                           select follow;

        //Set display names
        foreach (var item in followUpItem)
        {
            var key1 = int.Parse(item.Key1);

            var name = (from a in db.Agent
                               where key1 == a.SymetraNumber
                               select a).Single();

            item.DisplayName = name.FirstName + " " + name.LastName;
            if (!item.DisplayName.Equals(AgentName))
                followUpItem.Remove(item);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: oops, sorry. Started to write the question then got sidetracked by something else. Updated the post.

Comment: Collections and IQueryable should usually be plural IMHO, followUpItems, so you it's clear it represents a variable number of items, instead of a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
followUpItem = followUpItem.RemoveAll(i=> i.Id == item.Id);
```

Sorry that won't work on iqueryable.  Try this instead:

```
followUpItem = followUpItem.Where(i=> i.Id != item.Id);
```

This assumes Id's are never null.

You could also build a list of "items to be removed" and call .Except(itemsToRemove), **OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP**.  Modifying a list inside a loop will give you a headache sometimes ;)

```
followUpItem = followUpItem.Except(itemsToRemove);
```

Comment: .RemoveAll() isn't a System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable method

Comment: @NealR Yeh I realized that, see update with couple other options.

Comment: @NealR Last option is probably more efficient.  Some LINQ methods do not guarantee that order is maintained, you'll have to hunt around for documentation to see if that's one.